# Use Google Authenticator's Code Less feature with own websites or apps?

Tags: web-applications, two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

Google Authenticator has a nice feature, to authenticate code-less with a popup.
Some other apps also do have this feature:
- Battle.net Authenticator
- Microsoft Authenticator

Does anybody knows if it's possible to use this feature instead of the "old" TOTP?
It's quite handy to login with only a popup.

Maybe there is an Web-API to call the users authenticator if you first got a token or something like that.

thanks, 
sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are referring to Google Prompt, I am pretty sure its only Google Accounts that support this so far and not the actual API...I hope it will be some day.

Good piece taken from here: https://authy.com/blog/google-prompt-confirms-future-of-2fa-and-authentication-technologies/

> Want to build Google Prompt into your own applications?
>   Google Prompt is a great example of the future of authentication. But, what if you want to integrate it into your own applications? Google Prompt wasn’t designed for developers and businesses, it was designed for individual Google users. Same goes for Yahoo’s Account Key. They are fantastic additions to the security landscape, but they don’t greatly move the needle outside of their own respective ecosystems. Even if you want to integrate it, you lose the power to customize, shape and determine the experience for your users.

Comment: i got the same result, i couldn't find anything about the code less prompt with GAuth. maybe i'll try authy or connect some services directly to a google account :-)